# Postgres 9.3 on Linux - Resource utilization - Multiple vs one service services

Tags: linux, postgresql, resources, resource-management, postgresql-9.3

I'm consolidating multiple Linux boxes running Postgres into one box.

Given the way Postgres handles resource utilization, would one single server service handling all the databases provide a much better performance than multiple server services (each one listening to different IP:port) running on the same host?

Thanks

Comment: I think you already asked this here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/68592/7788 . Please don't copy & paste questions between sites, or *at least* link between them to avoid wasting everyone's time.

Comment: You don't provide any stats.  Include DB size, RAM amount, other serivces running, etc... Then you might get a real answer.